# Check if URL has certain string with PHP

Tags: php, string, url

I would like to know if some word is present in the URL.

For example, if word car is in the URL, like www.domain.com/car/ or www.domain.com/car/audi/ it would echo 'car is exist' and if there's nothing it would echo 'no cars'.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: This also depends if you just looking for the word car or if you also want the type of car or cars too. You might need preg_match, strpos, explode and in_array/array_search, really just depends. if you want something simple, just use strpos as suggested

Comment: You might find [`s($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])->contains('car')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L93) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: What if the url contains the word "scared"? Should that print "car is exist"? If not, most of the answers here are wrong.

Answer (score 261):

Try something like this. The first row builds your URL and the rest check if it contains the word "car".

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (strpos($url,'car') !== false) {
    echo 'Car exists.';
} else {
    echo 'No cars.';
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution but just be wary that this will match a URL that has car anywhere. For example `www.domain.com/car-pricing` or `www.domain.com/carparks` will validate and output `Car exists`. Maybe it doesn't matter in your case but for others it might be relevant!

Comment: `$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` `echo count(strpos($url,'category'));` gives me `1` regardless of whether `category` exist in the Url or not. Any idea why?

Comment: From PHP 8.0 onwards, you can also use `str_contains($url, 'car')`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php

Answer (score 91):

I think the easiest way is:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "car") !== false){
// car found
}
```

Comment: Perfect... I needed to match http://example.com/events/pagename to find any urls with "events" in them and it works!

Comment: I've used this several times in the past week on 4 different projects. Simple. Thanks.

Comment: This does not test the full url; only the path.  It will not test against the scheme, domain, port, query parameters, or fragment.

Answer (score 25):

```
$url = " www.domain.com/car/audi/";
if (strpos($url, "car")!==false){
    echo "Car here";
}
else {
   echo "No car here :(";
}
```

See [`strpos` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 16):

```
if( strpos( $url, $word ) !== false ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
// Check if URL contains the word "car" or "CAR"
   if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'car' )!==false){
   echo "Car here";
   } else {
   echo "No car here";
   }
```

```
If you want to use HTML in the echo, be sure to use ' ' instead of " ".
I use this code to show an alert on my webpage https://geaskb.nl/ 
where the URL contains the word "Omnik" 
but hide the alert on pages that do not contain the word "Omnik" in the URL.
```

Explanation stripos : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos

Answer (score 11):

worked for me with php

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'shop.php') !== false){
echo 'url contains shop';
}
```

Comment: This is essentially identical to [this three your old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28875202/466862). Why bother posting an answer like that?

Answer (score 4):

strstr didn't exist back then?

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "car")) {
   echo "car found";
}
```

This must be one of the easiest methods right?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function:

```
if(false !== strpos($url,'car')) {
    echo 'Car exists!';
}
else {
    echo 'No cars.';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely this is the correct way round....

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (!strpos($url,'mysql')) {
echo 'No mysql.'; //swapped with other echo statement
} else {
echo 'Mysql exists.';
}
```

Otherwise its reporting the opposite way it should...

Answer (score 2):

Starting with PHP 8 (2020-11-24), you can use [str_contains](//php.net/function.str-contains):

```
if (str_contains('www.domain.com/car/', 'car')) {
   echo 'car is exist';
} else {
   echo 'no cars';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try an .htaccess method similar to the concept of how wordpress works.

Reference: http://monkeytooth.net/2010/12/htaccess-php-how-to-wordpress-slugs/

But I'm not sure if thats what your looking for exactly per say..

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (!strpos($url,'car')) {
    echo 'Car exists.';
} else {
    echo 'No cars.';
}
```

This seems to work.

Comment: Wrong way around here.