# WordPress: check current URL is /cpt/something but not /cpt/something/var

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My WordPress site has a Custom Post Type "**car**", so I have something like `www.example.com/car/honda-civic-2013/`

Now I have also an action "buy" using [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) displaying specific information: `www.example.com/car/honda-civic-2013/buy`

In my `header.php` template, what is the appropriate way to check that the current page is not "buy"?

Here's what I have:

```
if (is_singular('car')) {
    echo "Click here to buy this car";
}
```

It works but it also displays "*Click here to buy this car*" on the /buy page which I want to avoid!

I want a permanent solution, meaning that I don't want to check against "buy" in particular, but check against ANY /sub-action so the above is echoed only on the main CustomPostType page.

Thank you for any help

Comment: I've never done this, but have seen [many good examples at WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=add_rewrite_endpoint+is%3Aa). . . . . I really like your username/avatar, nice trick!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more code heavy than you'd probably like, but this should work:

```
// Get the current URL
$url  = @( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on' ) ? 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] :  'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$url .= ( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] !== 80 ) ? ":" . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] : '';
$url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// If current URL is for cars and not the "buy" page
if ( is_singular('car') && !strpos($url,'/buy') ) {
    echo "Click here to buy this car";
}
```

**Sources:**

- https://gist.github.com/cferdinandi/6608505
- [Check if URL has certain string with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118823/check-if-url-has-certain-string-with-php/7118867#7118867)

Comment: Thanks but no thanks. I found a cleaner workaround using WordPress methods, see my answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wp_query;
if (is_singular('car') && !isset($wp_query->query['buy'])) {
    echo "Click here to buy this car";
}
```