# PHP - If page URL = "http://example.com/page", display image. Else, display another image

Tags: php, url, if-statement, selection

I have my template, and I want it to display a certain image if you are on certain page like `http://example.com/test` and **if you aren't on that page**, then **I want it to display another image**.

I also want it to display the image **if you are in any sub directory** like `http://example.com/test/stuff`

Also, is there a way to do this with multiple pages in the same code?

So like

```
if page = example.com/test then display testimg.jpg

if page = example.com/archive then display archive.jpg

else, display defaultimg.jpg
```

thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118823/check-if-url-has-certain-string-with-php

Comment: thanks, but didn't really answer my question. still not sure how to implement images with that. I'm rather new to PHP and still trying to learn the ropes.

Comment: Please consider posting your attempt(codewise). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( strpos($url, 'test') !== false ) {
    echo('<img src="image_path/testimg.jpg">');
}
elseif ( strpos($url, 'archive') !== false ) {
    echo('<img src="image_path/archive.jpg">');
}
else {
    echo('<img src="image_path/defaultimg.jpg">');
}
```

Comment: Function strpos() may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

U can also using strpbrk() function and get more compact code: (>PHP5)

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ( strpbrk($url, 'test') ) {
    echo('<img src="image_path/testimg.jpg">');
}
elseif ( strpbrk($url, 'archive') ) {
    echo('<img src="image_path/archive.jpg">');
}
else {
    echo('<img src="image_path/defaultimg.jpg">');
}
```