# HTML5 Form Input Type: Checking the input

Tags: php, html

I would like to check if the URL the user entered into the input box contains 'xyz' before sumbitting. I am aware this can be done with php after fetching the put, however can this be done in HTML5?

For example, here I put in a random word, and HTML5 tells me this is not a URL. 
[image: Like this]

Can i get it to check if the entered text contains something before submit?

My code

```
  <input type="url" name="tradeurl" placeholder="Steam Trade URL">
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
```

Comment: check out `stripos()`. Here, check out this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/7118823/ - they're using `strpos()` but that will fail if someone enters uppercase or mixed letters. `stripos()` is case-insensitive.

Comment: can't be done in html5, i'd do it in jQuery.

Comment: I'd opt for a server-side method myself. ^ JS can always be disabled. Plus, OP tagged as php.

Comment: Do Google "validate url with html5" many many hits. Use the "pattern" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, using the HTML5 `pattern` attribute as @fred-ii suggests like so:

```
<input type="url" name="tradeurl" placeholder="Steam Trade URL" pattern="[^ ]*(xyz)[^ ]*">
```

Even if you do this you need to validate server-side as well — it's easy to disable client-side (HTML/JavaScript) validation.