# How to change color of current page of navigation bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am able to get the navigation bar to change color for hover, active, and current. The problem is when the page loads it refreshes the navigation bar and the current page color reverts back. I believe the javascript is working as expected.

I found one method of doing this in which each web page has it's own navigation bar, which is not the greatest method of coding and only would be used if there are just a few pages to the website.

```js
/* 
 * https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp
 */

// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("navbar");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("current");

    // If there's no current class
    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" current", "");
    }

    // Add the current class to the current/clicked button
    this.className += " current";
  });
}
```

```css
/* Change background color of navbar links on hover */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  /* Yellow */
  color: #000000;
  /* Black */
}


/* Change background color of navbar links on active */

.btn:active {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  /* Red */
  color: #000000;
  /* Black */
}


/* Change background color of navbar links for current page */

.btn.current {
  background-color: #006600;
  /* Green */
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /* White */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  ...
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a class="btn" href="index.php">Home</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a class="btn" href="PlanYourVisit.php">New Here</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
      <div class="dropdownContent">
        <a class="btn" href="PlanYourVisit.php">Plan Your Visit</a>
        <a class="btn" href="YourKids.php">Your Kids</a>
        <a class="btn" href="TimeLocation.php">Time and Location</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I would like the navigation bar to keep the color green for the current page. The navigation turns green, then reverts to the default gray color I have for the navigation bar.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use JS? Since the site is already PHP (I assume), you can reference this answer to compare the button's URL to the actual URL and just output a class based on that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118823/check-if-url-has-certain-string-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to do this on page load NOT on click.

Simply loop through your navigation and see if the HREF matches the current URL.

```
<script>
    let current_url = document.location;
    document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .btn").forEach(function(e){
       if(e.href == current_url){
          e.classList += " current";
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I attempted this and I am missing something. I removed my javascript file, added:
    </div>
<script>
document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .btn").forEach(function(e){
   if(e.href == $current_url){
      e.classList += " current";
   }
});
</script>
</nav>
I added this line to index.php file:
$current_url = "https://test.websitenamet.org/index.php";

Comment: @JohnFischer this is all javascript, no need for PHP variables. I updated my answer to be less confusing.

Comment: The piece I was doing wrong with the new javascript code was I was mixing PHP variables with javascript variables. I place 
    current_url = "https://test.websitename.org/index.php";
in the index.php file and now it works. Each php file needs it's own definition of current_url.

<script>current_url = "https://test.websitename.org/index.php";</script>

Comment: @JohnFischer, no if you use the code as is without modifying it, it will work for every page. `document.location' in my code grabs the current URL.

Comment: Thanks iamvain2, you are correct. For some reason, I made it too complex. All I needed to do was replace my javascript with your javascript.