# Redirect of product URL in WooCommerce app

Tags: redirect, woocommerce, product

I want to redirect all single product page whose first link URL is **"product"** which will be redirected to **store** thank you page.
I want to keep the single products, I just want the product with the path `/product/` at the beginning to redirect. Since I'm currently using a product that doesn't have `/product/`, I need to remove from duplicate.

For example:

```
domain.com/product/category/product-name

domain.com/product/product-name

move to

domain.com/shop
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [WooCommerce: Single Product Page Redirect for Logged In Customers](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-single-product-page-redirect-for-logged-in-customers/) the following snippet should work for all your single product pages:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bbloomer_single_product_redirect );
 
function bbloomer_single_product_redirect() { 
    if ( ! is_product() ) return;  
    wp_safe_redirect( '/shop' );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Oh @businessbloomer , I also like your blog,
Sorry I didn't explain correctly.
I want to keep the single products, I just want the product with the path /product/ at the beginning to redirect.
Since I'm currently using a product that doesn't have /product/, I need to remove from duplicate

Comment: Gotcha. You can use the same snippet and also check if the current URL contains /product/ - and only then do the redirect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118823/check-if-url-has-certain-string-with-php